# Using a statement to prove its converse

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Suppose that we use $P\implies Q$ in a proof of its converse $Q\implies P$. If we can then establish by other means that $P\implies Q$ is true, does this mean that we have proved $P\iff Q$? Or is the first proof faulty in some regard for having used an implication in the proof of its own converse?

Comment: This is valid and happened in a Geometry class I took last semester. Looking for my notes now to provide an example

Comment: I think this is valid, as long as you do not use $Q \rightarrow P$ to prove $P \rightarrow Q$ as well. That would result in a circular argument which is invalid.

Comment: @Nasenhaar: not so - see my answer.

Comment: There's a popular theorem in functional analysis that requires you do this. I definitely felt a bit dirty doing it lol.

Comment: @CameronWilliams: what is that theorem? Do the proofs not observe that once you have $(P \implies Q) \implies (Q \implies P)$ then you have $Q \implies P$?

Comment: You've prove (P->Q)->(Q->P) and you've proven P->Q is true.  So Q->P is true.  So if P then Q.  And if Q then P.  Yep.  Proven P <-> Q.

Comment: @RobArthan I don't remember. It's been more than three years. Obviously it's fine, but it's just a bit different is all.

Comment: @fleablood: you don't need to prove that $P\implies Q$ is true to conclude that $Q \implies P$ is true. See my answer.

Comment: @CameronWilliams: it must have been like one of those really popular songs, whose title you immediately forget $\ddot{\smile}$. If you do remember, please let us know.

Comment: You may not need to but the OP said we *did* so.... I took the easy way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To assume the converse of an implication when trying to prove the implication is not only not faulty, it is actually an admissible proof technique: if you have proved $(P \implies Q) \implies (Q \implies P)$, then you can prove $Q \implies P$ regardless of  whether $P \implies Q$ is provable or not. To see this, either reason thus in natural deduction style:

1. $(P \implies Q) \implies (Q \implies P)$ (assumption)
2. $Q$ (assumption)
3. $P \implies Q$ (2, $\implies$-introduction discharging the (non-existent) assumption $P$)
4. $Q \implies P$ (1, 3, $\implies$-elimination)
5. $P$ (2, 4, $\implies$-elimination)
6. $Q \implies P$ (5, $\implies$-introduction discharging assumption 2)
7. $((P \implies Q) \implies (Q \implies P)) \implies (Q \implies P)$ (6, $\implies$-introduction discharging assumption 1).

or draw up the truth table for the formula in step 7.

So at the end of your first proof, you can conclude that $Q \implies P$ with no assumption. Then if you can prove $P \implies Q$, you have proved $P \iff Q$.

Comment: I wrote out the truth tables, and (assuming I didn't make a mistake), I got that $((P\implies Q)\implies(Q\implies P))$ is logically equivalent to $Q\implies P$ and that the formula in step 7 is a tautology. This still means we can conclude $Q\implies P$ as long as we have $((P\implies Q)\implies(Q\implies P))$. Does this seem right?

Comment: @RobArthan: I think there are two typos in your derivation. In steps 6 and 7 you use $\Rightarrow$-introduction, not elimination.

Comment: @Taroccoesbrocco: thanks. I've fixed the typos.

Comment: Rob's proof in the form of a program: $\lambda F:(P\to Q)\to(Q\to P).\lambda q:Q.F(\lambda p:P.q)(q)$